# Change the return value for a particular field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few JavaScript functions like the one below...

```
<input type="text" id="myField">
<script>
    $("#myField").val("10:20:30"); 

    function doNotEditIt(fieldId){ // this function can't be edited!

        var myVar = $("#" + fieldId).val(); // it's 10:20:30, i want 10.2030
        // ... code which converts the value
    }
</script>
```

...which I can't edit or change them, because they are universal for all of my previous fields. I want add new fields to my page (like myField; see below) and use functions which are not customised specifically for them.

Is it possible to change the format of a returning value? For example...

```
$("#myField").changeReturningFormat(function(){ 
  // ... code which change format
});
```

...or change the display format? For example...

```
$("#myField").val('10.2030'); // a user will see 10:20:30
```

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "_change the format of returning value_" Do you mean the value which is read at server-side?

Answer (score 4):

Check the below sample, you just need to use `replace()`:

```js
var str = "10:20:30";
str = str.replace(/:/, '.');
console.log(str.replace(/:/, ''))
```